# How much users Joomla 3 can handle at once?

Tags: joomla3.0

I plan to build a site based on Joomla 3 CMS and client says that they will have from 750 to 1000 registered users per a day.
I wonder whether Joomla 3 is able to handle all those users at once or not?

Answer (score 0):

That is a rather broad question.

It depends on how you have optimised your site and what type of hosting platform you are using. A $10/year shared platform obviously wouldn't work with Joomla! with that many users.

Joomla! is very efficient and shouldn't have any problems with this, but if you start adding in lots of plugins, components and modules which are not off a great quality then it will effect performance. Hence the broadness of your question.